# How do I code this in Brainfuck?

Tags: brainfuck

You are given an upper case alphabet C and a single digit number K. Print the alphabet D which is K the alphabet in the order,

That is, print a single character C+K

For example:

```
A+3 = D
Q+9 = Z
```

Input Format

The single line of input consists of two characters, C and K, not space separated (refer sample input)

Constraints:

It is guaranteed that the input character will be from 'A' to 'Q' and number 1 to 9 so you don't have to worry about boundary conditions.

Output Format

Print a single upper case character

> Sample Input
>
> A3
>
> Sample Output
>
> D

This is what I have so far.

```
, > , ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
```

Comment: Classical copy&paste homework dump, I assume ...?

Comment: Not a homework just a challenge I was going through. Please help if you can.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far first.

Comment: @CBroe Except that I really don't see any professor gives out assignments in Brainfuck. Unless the professor is a sadist. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Haha, Actually I just got to know about this language, don't worry; I'm getting close. Give some hints if you know about this.

Comment: I know *about* the language, and even written my own very simple (and not very sophisticated and probably not fully working) interpreter for it. But I don't claim to know anything about the language really, not enough to be able to help you unfortunately.

Comment: @CBroe So much hate for homework people, huh? Anyway, I got the solution. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: No, but SO simply is not the place to just drop your requirements without showing that you made any efforts on your own. This just happens frequently with homework assignments, but in other cases (such as this one) too.

Comment: @CBroe My bad, I could've posted the tried code but I'm completely a newbie to this. Cheers.

Comment: @KashifFarazShamsi : I accidentally landed on this page, but I too want to F**k my brain with BF. Could you please point out to the official download links. Thanks.

Comment: @Koder101 what download link? you can google any online interpreter or even better, make your own: it's an hour of work if you're slow and you're guaranteed to know how it works at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have landed up on a solution.

Here is the code.

```
, > , ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- --- [< + > -] <.
```

Comment: This was not a homework guys, just goofing around the newly found language.

Comment: Thanks, @Sirmyself   :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an other solution:

```
,>, >+++++[<--- --- --->-]<--- [<+>-]<.
```

instead of counting every '-' or '+', I like to make mathematical functions that will input the number I want in fewer characters. In the previous example, I did 5*-9 -3 = -48

I could also do this

```
,>, >+++ +++[<---- ---->-] <[<+>-]<.
```

6x-8 = -48